# AJAX POST data not being sent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

On button click, i want to post the contents of the email text box. When i click the login button nothing happens.

My File dir:

Model/                <-- configuration.php is inside Model dir.

View/

Controller/

index.php             <-- calls the header, body, and footer php classes that are in the view dir

```
                    <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" name="loginButton" id="loginButton" name="loginButton" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <p>Not a member? <a href="View/registration.php">Sign Up</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#loginButton").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Model/configuration.php?action=login",
                data: "email=" + $("#email").val(),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("result");
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

PHP file

```
<?php

if($_GET['action'] == "login") {
    print_r($_POST);
}

?>
```

Comment: can you post the php script? is it even being called?

Comment: "This is not working" is the most useless problem description. Please explain what exactly the problem is and what you have tried.

Comment: Posted the php file.

Comment: Do you send the request in your console or do you see any errors?

Comment: No errors. The alert box showing the result just doesnt show

Comment: Do you added the jquery plugin in starting https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: i have:

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your if condition had an extra parentheses.

Try this:

```
<?php

if($_GET['action'] == "login") {
    print_r($_POST);
}

?>
```

Comment: the reason GET is being used is to get the action from the url
Model/configuration.php?action=login
i use post to get the post data

Comment: Yes, you are right about the GET. Try it now, your code had an extra ")" on the if condition.

Comment: I didnt even notice that, thanks, but even after changing that, it still isnt working.

Comment: is the script being called? You can use https://developer.chrome.com/devtools to confirm.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function"

Comment: You didn't include the jquery on the page. Try adding this on top of the html `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Im pretty sure i do, i  have: 

<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"; integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJw‌​FDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5K‌​kN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

in my header

Comment: Try changing with this `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#loginButton").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Model/configuration.php?action=login",
                data: {email:$("#email").val()},
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("result");
                }
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize your form and pass to data.

```
data: $("#FormId").serialize()
```

See also https://api.jquery.com/serialize/